# Root node creation in db2 xml

Tags: db2

i am able to create the xml node in db2 but all the node creation i need under root node.

below code i have written as:

```
CREATE FUNCTION abc.sample(v_pf_wkstn_oid_sh smallint, 
                v_pf_wkstn_oid_lng integer,
                v_llr_oid_sh smallint,
                v_llr_oid_lng integer )

RETURNS xml

LANGUAGE SQL

BEGIN ATOMIC

DECLARE v_RtKeys xml;

SET v_RtKeys=(SELECT XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(
              NAME "TableKeys",
              XMLELEMENT(
              NAME "rt", XMLAttributes( rt.rbase_field_name AS "rbase_field_name",
                                                   rt.wkstn_oid_sh AS "wkstn_oid_sh", 
                           rt.wkstn_oid_lng AS "wkstn_oid_lng",
                           rt_key_sqnc_num AS "rt_key_sqnc_num", 
                                   rt.rt_key_rtrvl_cd AS "rt_key_rtrvl_cd",
                           pf_wkstn_oid_sh AS "pf_wkstn_oid_sh", 
                           pf_wkstn_oid_lng AS "pf_wkstn_oid_lng", 
                           'N' as status_indc, 
                           rt.field_data_type AS "field_data_type", 
                           rt.field_size AS "field_size",
                           'Rate Key            ' as "DisplayType",
                           '' as "Author",
                           0 as "DateCreated"),
                XMLELEMENT(
                NAME "rb", XMLAttributes( rb.field_level_indc AS "field_level_indc",
                           rb.field_scope_indc AS "field_scope_indc")))) order by rt_key_sqnc_num asc ) 
                           FROM RATABASE.rt_tmplt_key rt inner join RATABASE.rbase_field_dict rb  
                                        on rb.rbase_field_name=rt.rbase_field_name 
                                        where pf_wkstn_oid_sh = v_pf_wkstn_oid_sh
                                                                                AND pf_wkstn_oid_lng = v_pf_wkstn_oid_lng 
                                                                                AND rb.llr_oid_lng = v_llr_oid_lng
                                                                                AND rb.llr_oid_sh = v_llr_oid_sh);

RETURN v_RtKeys;

END
```

once i have executed the above sample for each time i am getting  for all rt node as below means multiple TableKeys

```
<TableKeys><rt rbase_field_name="ITEM NUM 4A                                       " wkstn_oid_sh="100" wkstn_oid_lng="2051" rt_key_sqnc_num="1" rt_key_rtrvl_cd="E" pf_wkstn_oid_sh="100" pf_wkstn_oid_lng="2050" STATUS_INDC="N" field_data_type="N" field_size="4" DisplayType="Rate Key            " Author="" DateCreated="0"><rb field_level_indc="I" field_scope_indc="D"/></rt></TableKeys><TableKeys><rt rbase_field_name="ITEM NUM 1A                                       " wkstn_oid_sh="100" wkstn_oid_lng="2052" rt_key_sqnc_num="2" rt_key_rtrvl_cd="R" pf_wkstn_oid_sh="100" pf_wkstn_oid_lng="2050" STATUS_INDC="N" field_data_type="N" field_size="1" DisplayType="Rate Key            " Author="" DateCreated="0"><rb field_level_indc="I" field_scope_indc="D"/></rt></TableKeys><TableKeys><rt rbase_field_name="ITEM NUM 1B                                       " wkstn_oid_sh="100" wkstn_oid_lng="2053" rt_key_sqnc_num="3" rt_key_rtrvl_cd="R" pf_wkstn_oid_sh="100" pf_wkstn_oid_lng="2050" STATUS_INDC="N" field_data_type="N" field_size="1" DisplayType="Rate Key            " Author="" DateCreated="0"><rb field_level_indc="I" field_scope_indc="D"/></rt></TableKeys><TableKeys><rt rbase_field_name="ITEM NUM 1C                                       " wkstn_oid_sh="100" wkstn_oid_lng="2054" rt_key_sqnc_num="4" rt_key_rtrvl_cd="R" pf_wkstn_oid_sh="100" pf_wkstn_oid_lng="2050" STATUS_INDC="N" field_data_type="N" field_size="1" DisplayType="Rate Key            " Author="" DateCreated="0"><rb field_level_indc="I" field_scope_indc="D"/></rt></TableKeys><TableKeys><rt rbase_field_name="ITEM NUM 1D                                       " wkstn_oid_sh="100" wkstn_oid_lng="2055" rt_key_sqnc_num="5" rt_key_rtrvl_cd="R" pf_wkstn_oid_sh="100" pf_wkstn_oid_lng="2050" STATUS_INDC="N" field_data_type="N" field_size="1" DisplayType="Rate Key            " Author="" DateCreated="0"><rb field_level_indc="I" field_scope_indc="D"/></rt></TableKeys><TableKeys><rt rbase_field_name="ITEM NUM 1E                                       " wkstn_oid_sh="100" wkstn_oid_lng="2056" rt_key_sqnc_num="6" rt_key_rtrvl_cd="R" pf_wkstn_oid_sh="100" pf_wkstn_oid_lng="2050" STATUS_INDC="N" field_data_type="N" field_size="1" DisplayType="Rate Key            " Author="" DateCreated="0"><rb field_level_indc="I" field_scope_indc="D"/></rt></TableKeys>
```

i need only one inside that all rt and rb node in db2 sample.

please suggest have a look this code provide your input.

Answer (score 1):

```
with t (rbase_field_name, field_level_indc) as (values
  ('ITEM NUM 4A', 'I')
, ('ITEM NUM 4C', 'J')
)
SELECT 
--XMLSERIALIZE(
  XMLELEMENT(
    NAME "TableKeys"
  , XMLAGG (
      XMLELEMENT(
        NAME "rt"
      , XMLATTRIBUTES(t.rbase_field_name as "rbase_field_name")
      , XMLELEMENT(
          Name "rb"
        , XMLATTRIBUTES(t.field_level_indc as "field_level_indc")
        )
      ) order by t.rbase_field_name
    )
  ) 
--as varchar(1000))
FROM t;
```

The result is:

```
<TableKeys>
  <rt rbase_field_name="ITEM NUM 4A">
    <rb field_level_indc="I"/>
  </rt>
  <rt rbase_field_name="ITEM NUM 4C">
    <rb field_level_indc="J"/>
  </rt>
</TableKeys>
```

BTW, it would be good if you provided some sample data which your query returns, and desired result in a better formatted mode than you did it.